# JavaScript function importing doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript

I'm referring the code below.
https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/complete-javascript-course/blob/master/9-forkify/final/src/js/views/searchView.js

I made a function and tried to import the function to another js file but it doesn't work. If I write "elements.searchInput.value;" it won't work while if I do "console.log(elements.searchInput.value)" it will work. I'm doing exactly the same as the reference file but just wondering why my code doesn't work.

```
index.js

import "./../styles/style.scss";
import Search from './models/Search';
import * as searchView from './views/SearchView';
import { key, proxy } from './config';
import { elements } from './views/Base';

const state = {};

const controlSearch = async () => {
    const query = searchView.getInput(); // <- This doesn't work
    console.log(query) // Get nothing

    if(query) { // <- Can't get in to this part
        state.search = new Search(query);
        console.log("New Search", state);
    }
}

elements.searchForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    event.preventDefault();
    controlSearch();
});
```

```
searchView.js

import { elements } from './base';

export const getInput = () => {
    elements.searchInput.value; // This code won't show up in controlSearch function

export const clearInput = () => {
    elements.searchInput.value = '';
};
```

```
base.js

export const elements = {
    searchForm: document.querySelector('.search'),
    searchResult: document.querySelector('.movie_list'),
    searchInput: document.querySelector('.search__field')
}
```

```
Search.js

import { key } from '../config';

export default class Search {
    constructor(query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    async getResults() {
        try {
            const res = await axios(`http://`);
            this.result = res.data.results;
        }

        catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is error ? Also name the file

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" and "won't show", are there any errors in the dev console? Or is the content  of `query` just empty?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, yes query is empty. It supposed to be elements.searchInput.value. Also there's no error showing up...

Comment: `search__field` two `_`? is that right?

Comment: "`console.log(query) // Get nothing`" like undefined? Try `const query = await searchView.getInput();`

Comment: It was actually undefine even after I added await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is your problem here

```
export const getInput = () => {
    elements.searchInput.value;
```

You are not returning anything
change it to

```
export const getInput = () => elements.searchInput.value;
```

or

```
export const getInput = () => {
    return elements.searchInput.value; 
}
```

Comment: also, opening the link you sent, I believe that's what was done too

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I thought I did the same thing but seems like I did something wrong. Also my return didn't work at first for some reason... maybe incorrect syntax. Anyway thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

Getter functions have to return a value.

```
const yourFunction = () => { return yourVariable };
```

Or with the arrow function you can use:

```
const yourFunction = () => yourVariable;
```

Comment: Returning a value was the solution that I came up, but when I did like export const getInput = () => 'elements.searchInput.value', it doesn't recognize the value of searchInput but it just took it as a string "elements.searchInput.value"

Comment: Of course you have to return your variable instead of my text or a string. But you have to return something. `const yourFunction = () => { return yourVariable; }` or `const yourFunction = () => yourVariable;`... This is just an exmaple i will edit it.